# Conflicting information about CUDA compute capability

Tags: cuda, hardware, gpu, nvidia

I am looking for a GPU of compute capability 3.x.

Unfortunatly, there is contradictory data on the compute capabilities of the GTX6xx cards on NVIDIA's site:

http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/cuda_gpus_uk.html

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

For example, the GeForce GTX650 is listed as 3.0 according to the first source and 2.1 according to the second.

Which one is correct?

Can someone that has a GTX650 confirm which compute capability it has?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the second link is correct, but this discrepancy is confusing. I have a GeForce GTX 660 Ti and it's certainly a cc 3.0 GPU (which agrees with the second link and disagrees with the first). `cudaGetDeviceProperties()` returns 3.0 for the compute capability of this GPU as well.

Comment: I bought it and it was indeed a 3.0 compute capabilities

Answer (score 3):

I think the page at http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/cuda_gpus_uk.html is in error. I think the source of the error is that, after releasing Kepler (GTX6xx), NVIDIA rebranded a series of their older products to use the 6xx designator, which is certainly misleading, or at least confusing, for many customers. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_600_Series):

- The GeForce 605 (OEM) card is a rebranded GeForce 510.
- The GeForce GT 610 card is a rebranded GeForce GT 520.
- The GeForce GT 620 (OEM) card is a rebranded GeForce GT 520.
- The GeForce GT 620 card is a rebranded GeForce GT 530.
- The GeForce GT 630 (DDR3) card is a rebranded GeForce GT 440 (DDR3).
- The GeForce GT 630 (GDDR5) card is a rebranded GeForce GT 540 (GDDR5).
- The GeForce GT 640 (OEM) card is a rebranded GeForce GT 545 (DDR3).
- The GeForce GT 645 (OEM) card is a rebranded GeForce GTX 560 SE.

I guess an error was made in the list on the first page as to which products had been rebranded.